# Android Sinch PubNubListener: Permanently failing subscribe after 6 attempts

Tags: sinch, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

I get these errors on Samsung tab S3 and Galaxy S8 and more devices.
I suspect that this prevents me from establishing an app to app connection.
Any ideas what to configure to solve this?

Caller:

```
W/PubNubListener: Attempt 0 -> IO exception while subscribing for data. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubListener: Attempt 1 -> IO exception while subscribing for data. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubListener: Attempt 2 -> IO exception while subscribing for data. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubListener: Attempt 3 -> IO exception while subscribing for data. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubListener: Attempt 4 -> IO exception while subscribing for data. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubListener: Attempt 5 -> IO exception while subscribing for data. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
E/PubNubListener: Permanently failing subscribe after 6 attempts.
```

Callee:

```
W/PubNubPublisher: Attempt 0 -> IO exception while publishing. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubPublisher: Attempt 1 -> IO exception while publishing. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubPublisher: Attempt 2 -> IO exception while publishing. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubPublisher: Attempt 3 -> IO exception while publishing. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubPublisher: Attempt 4 -> IO exception while publishing. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
W/PubNubPublisher: Attempt 5 -> IO exception while publishing. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
E/PubNubPublisher: Permanent failure for publishing (after 6 attempts) message: 10 7f94c2a4-90d4-4f14-8c48-7f38adf20eb2 - 0 1 opLX7zLmxBxnNsYWjWDPd+hxK8PqPsZhaSGVrqFebNIEeEsrFH0aqWJf9Z+ys4bd1RsrWaAHBX24PU4RHym8Xaw1UfFL1jM3kb4ZESKg0RFIX8nD3bK5TEJQfTEeMZ6xKVdBYOOp9qgnnZWv9rmz0wOogq90ZFiYfkIeryxl0MMaPkfhnImowaPbY9vz3c1RjBJh02iRFpCnOJY3xpi+ZZwy+N8xa7VdyMDwqRpNm2sXVZSWkOyBTsXCKDRXZwIM
```

Comment: what version of the sinch sdk are you using?

Comment: sinch sdk version 3.12.5

Comment: sorry for late comment, do you still have this problem?

Comment: I reached out to Sinch support and they ended up updating their sdk which solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the new Sinch Android SDK version 3.12.6